# Is there any implementation of push notification backed that I can readily use

Tags: node.js, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a PWA where I should implement push notification.

1. I want all subscribed users ( end points ) should be added to a list
   in backed
2. Where a notifications can be pushed to all the subscribers ( end
   points )
3. When user unsubscribed that end point entry should be
           removed

Is there any readily available nodejs or other implementation so I no need to write all that back end code ?

Comment: You might also look into [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Answer (score 1):

There are few Node modules that you can use to greatly simplify your job if you're going to implement it yourself:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-notification
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-notify
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pn

There is also this project:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushserver

> Push Server is a cross-plateform push server based on node-apn and node-gcm. Push Server currently supports iOS (APN) and android (GCM) platforms. It uses mongoDB to store the push tokens. Note that this server is not meant to be used as a front facing server as there's no particular security implemented.

Comment: Thank you @rsp, Will node-pushserver will work for browser push notifications ?